# Which approach is better for building Java code using Docker and Jenkins?

Tags: java, docker, jenkins, gradle, dockerfile

Approach 1: Using Jenkins, clone and build the code using gradle plugin, then add the JAR in the
dockerfile with JRE as a base image. As we have the JAR packed in the image, we can pull the
image and run the container.

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
ADD build/libs/abcd.jar abcd.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/abcd.jar"]
```

Approach 2: Create a dockerfile with all build dependencies now using Jenkins just build the dockerfile. Upload the image on dockerhub or ACR and for deploying just pull the image and run.

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre
"install gradle set the path variable"
"Run the gradle build"
"deploy the jar"
```

Just asking in a generalized way. Which will be better?

Comment: You can use approach 2 with a multi-stage build - i.e. have the first state based on a JDK with all the code and Gradle and build the deployable and then a second stage with just the JRE and COPY the jar from the first stage to the second. But you’d need to ask yourself, what does that give me over using Docker based workers in Jenkins - which will be easier to maintain. I would suggest there’s a third approach - don’t use Docker at all, use Jib.

Comment: Beware, Stack Overflow will close opinion-based questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approach 2 does not make sense at all. This would mean you have all the build tools and artifacts in your deployment unit (the image).

Approach 1 is pretty much the standard way to build a docker image as the deployment unit.